# in operator for sequences comporting weird in Dafny

Tags: seq, dafny

How can I help Dafny to proof that the following two assertions are the same:

```
method foo(xs : seq<int>)
  requires forall x :: x in xs ==> 0 <= x < 5;
{
  assert forall x :: x in xs ==> 0 <= x < 5;
  assert forall i :: 0 <= i < |xs| ==> 0 <= xs[i] < 5;
}
```

Also, Dafny seems to be able to proof that the following are the same. Why is that?

```
predicate test(value : int) {
  0 <= value < 5
}

method foo'(xs : seq<int>)
  requires forall x :: x in xs ==> test(x);
{
  assert forall i :: 0 <= i < |xs| ==> test(xs[i]);
}
```

[Example on Rise4Fun](https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/jvvY2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with quantifier triggers. You can read more about triggers in the [Dafny FAQ](https://github.com/microsoft/dafny/wiki/FAQ#how-does-dafny-handle-quantifiers-ive-heard-about-triggers-what-are-those).

In this case, the reason the final assertion fails in your first example is that `forall` quantifier in both the `requires` clause and the first assertion is triggered on `x in xs`.<sup>1</sup> This means that this quantified fact *will not be used* at value `v` except when `v in xs` is "in scope" for the verifier. To prove the second assertion, the verifier needs to use the earlier quantified fact at value `xs[i]`, but `xs[i] in xs` is not "in scope". This may sound strange, because `xs[i] in xs` is always true, but it turns out that the verifier cannot figure this out without your help.

So to prove the second assertion, you need to get the fact `xs[i] in xs` in scope somehow. One way is to change the assertion to

```
assert forall i :: 0 <= i < |xs| ==> xs[i] in xs && 0 <= xs[i] < 5;
```

(adding `xs[i] in xs` to the conclusion). In fact, once this new assertion is proved, Dafny can *then* prove your second assertion afterward, because this new assertion is triggered on `xs[i]`, which is also "in scope" in your second assertion.

Finally, the reason your second example verifies is because introducing the predicate `test` has changed the available triggers. Now the `forall` from the `requires` clause is triggered on both `x in xs` *and* `test(x)`. The new trigger is matches in the new version of the assertion in the body of `foo`, since `test(xs[i])` appears already. This causes the first `forall` to be instantiated correctly which means the assertion passes. Introducing otherwise-useless named predicates like this is a common trick when massaging triggers to get them to do what you want.

---

1. You can see what triggers are being used by hovering your mouse over the `forall` in your IDE, or by running on the command line with the option `/printTooltips`. You should see something like `Selected triggers: {x in xs}` for the first assertion in your first example.